# .htaccess redirect issue, only works on first load of webpage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am applying 301 Redirects for my old pages/directories using .htaccess.

However, strangely, it seems that redirects only on the first load of page.

Example steps:

1. I am redirecting "/page1.html" to "http://www.test.com/page/1/"
2. I uploaded my new .htaccess file containing all the links.
3. I accessed "page1.html" through my browser, it worked perfectly!
4. I re-entered the same URL for "page1.html", and hit Enter, but it is now redirecting to an incorrect URL. Very strange!
5. I re-uploaded the .htaccess, that is having no changes whatsoever, I re-entered the same URL, and worked again.
6. Re-entered again, then again failed.

Very strange guys right? Do you have any solution for this problem? Or maybe an explanation why it is behaving very strangely?

Comment: Can you provide your `.htaccess`?  What is the "incorrect URL" that you're being redirected to the second time?

Comment: Hi Edward, thanks for replying. My sample .htaccess is as follows: 
Redirect /cms/index.php/First-Page.html http://www.test.com/site/First-Page/ [R=301,L]

It works ONLY on first load, right after I uploaded the .htaccess to the server, but on 2nd, 3rd, etc; it is redirected to something like:
http://www.test.com/site/First-Page.html which is an invalid page thefore returning a 404 Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking this as a solved. It turns out it was just a browser's cache issue.
To avoid this rookie mistake, test your htaccess redirects via incognito window or in private browsing which are built-in features of our browsers. Or, you can clear your cache everytime you test. :-)